# How to determine if the content of one file is included in the content of another file

Tags: linux, shell, diff

First, my apologies for what is perhaps a rather stupid question that doesn't quite belong here.

Here's my problem: I have two large text files containing a lot of file names, let's call them A and B, and I want to determine if A is a subset of B, disregarding order, i.e. for each file name in A, find if file name is also in B, otherwise A is not a subset.

I know how to preprocess the files (to remove anything but the file name itself, removing different capitalization), but now I'm left to wonder if there is a simple way to perform the task with a shell command.

Diff probably doesn't work, right? Even if I 'sort' the two files first, so that at least the files that are present in both will be in the same order, since A is probably a *proper* subset of B, diff will just tell me that every line is different.

Again, my apologies if the question doesn't belong here, and in the end, if there is no easy way to do it I will just write a small program to do the job, but since I'm trying to get a better handle on the shell commands, I thought I'd ask here first.

Comment: good question! +1 ;) what is your problem with using `sort` and `diff`. Looks good for me.

Comment: Maybe my understanding of diff is lacking, but say file A contains:

aaa
ccc

and B contains:
aaa
bbb
ccc

diff will only tell me that line 2 is a mismatch, but what I want it to do is to tell me that ccc is *somewhere* found in B. If that option of diff exists, I'm not aware of it, even after reading the man page.

Comment: so you want to do a line-based including check, not the block-based (the whole content of the file as block)?

Comment: @Kent: yes, that's the idea. Sorry, I realize my original question wasn't phrased very clear in that respect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do this:

```
cat b | sort -u | wc
cat a b | sort -u | wc
```

If you get the same result, a is a subset of b.

Comment: Seems to work (on two small test files). Now I only have to find out *why* it works. But that's my problem, so: thanks!

Comment: get it now :) very smart solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it in awk

```
awk '
    # read A, the supposed subset file
    FNR == NR {a[$0]; next}
    # process file B
    $0 in a {delete a[$0]}
    END {if (length(a) == 0) {print "A is a proper subset of B"}}
' A B
```

Answer (score 0):

Test if an XSD file is a subset of a WSDL file:

```
xmllint --format file.wsdl | awk '{$1=$1};1' | sort -u | wc
xmllint --format file.wsdl file.xsd | awk '{$1=$1};1' | sort -u | wc
```

This adapts the elegant concept of RichieHindle's prior [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16349579/392033) using:

1. `xmllint --format` instead of `cat`, to pretty print the XML so each XML element was on one line, as required by `sort -u | wc`. Other pretty printing commands might work here, e.g. `jq .` for json.
2. an `awk` [command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205854) to normalise the whitespace: strip leading and trailing (because the indentation is different in both files), and collapse internal. Caveat: does not consider XML attribute order within the element.